# Gerrit WebUI setup on amazon ec2 not invoking using browser

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, gerrit

I am trying to install gerrit on an amazon ec2 instance. Amazon ec2 has a public and a private IP. I tried the following steps:

```
CREATE USER 'gerrit2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
CREATE DATABASE reviewdb;
ALTER DATABASE reviewdb charset=latin1;
GRANT ALL ON reviewdb.* TO 'gerrit2'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

- This is OK

```
sudo adduser gerrit2
sudo su gerrit2
cd ~gerrit2
java -jar gerrit.war init -d review_site
```

Then an interactive CLI setup took place. Almost all the options were default, except:
Git home:/home/gerrit2/git
DB:mysql
Cannonical url: http://:8080

After this I got this message:

```
Initialized /home/gerrit2/review_site
Executing /home/gerrit2/review_site/bin/gerrit.sh start
Starting Gerrit Code Review: OK
Waiting for server on <canonical url> ... OK
Opening http://<canonical url>:8080/#/admin/projects/ ...FAILED
Open Gerrit with a JavaScript capable browser:
http://<canonical url>:8080/#/admin/projects/
```

But when I hit the url with a browser on my laptop, I get:
The connection has timed out

```
The server at cannonical is taking too long to respond.
```

When I do a netstat -tulpn, it shows the following, which I assume is correct:

```
tcp        0      0 :::29418                    :::*                        LISTEN      26243/GerritCodeRev 
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      26243/GerritCodeRev
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does your security configuration (ec2) allow the access to port 8080 from the outside world?

Comment: Ohh thanks. So silly of me. Enabled the port for outside world and the page loaded, however, registering is a difficult job here, it seems. Logging in via google gives 400 error, telling it's an unregistered domain.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the not reachability, as one of the commenter noticed, it seems to have been the Security Group setting.

For your login issue: try to set the cannonicalWebUrl in your gerrit.config to the AWS external host name.